# Include open layer screenshot inside whole page screen shot

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, html2canvas, openlayers-5

I had div - let call him 'global'- that inside him I had title and two maps of openlayer.
I can get a snapshot of the global by html2canvs in this way:

```
    html2canvas(globalElement).then((canvas) => {
      this.screenShot(canvas.toDataURL());
    });
```

But the openlayers in the snapshot appeared as tow black div's like this:
[image]

I can get the open layer view separately by this code:

```
     this.map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
          const canvas = event.context.canvas;
          console.log(canvas.toDataURL()); // the open layer screen shot
       });
     this.map.renderSync();
```

How can I get all this together as one screenshot?

----- edit ----

With the help of @Mike I am using domtoImage like this example:

```
     this.map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
         domtoimage.toPng(globalElement)
        .then((dataURL) => {
            console.log(dataURL);
        });
       });
     this.map.renderSync();
```

and I can get the image of all the div with the open layer map.
A new question came up by this, the mat-icons of angular material didn't display properly with domtoimage, it shows the name of the icon and not the icon.
How can I fix this?

Comment: OpenLayers 6 will have a canvas for each layer and the example https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/export-map.html has been changed to use domtoimage  That would probably work for a whole page with any version of OpenLayers.

Comment: @Mike working very good but the angular icons didn't display in the screenshot,
do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: That will be an Angular issue, I suggest you add Angular.and domtoimage to the tags